# Determining the Big-O of Java Code

Tags: java, big-o

My Computer Science professor started teaching us about big O notation today and I had a hard time understanding it. Here are the examples he gave us:

1. What is the big O of the following:

   a. 4n2 + 2 is: **O(n^2) ?**

   b. n2 + 14n + 6 is: **O(n^2) ?**

   c. 5n3 + 10n2 – n – 8 is: **O(n^3) ?**

   d. 3n2 + 2n is: **O(n^2) ?**

I understand that it has to do with how long the program would take to run based on the input and how much it would increase depending on that input changing. I looked up a method for determining the big O of the above problems and put what I thought they were. But when it comes to determining the big O of Java code I am lost. Could someone point me in the right direction for these problems.

```
3. int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
i = n; 
count += 1;
}
// end for

4. int total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
 for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
  for (int k = 1; three < j; j++) {
total += 1;
} //end for } // end for } // end for

5. int total = 0;
 for (int one = 1; one <= n; one++) {
  for (int two = 1; two < n; two++) {
   for (int three = 1; three < 10; three++) {
total += 1;
} //end for } // end for } // end for

6. int total = 0;
for (int pass = 1; pass <= n; pass*=2) {
total += 1;
}
// end for

7. p = n;
while (n>1) {
 n = n/2;
  while (p>0) {
    p = p - 1;
}
// end while } // end while

8. for (int i = 1; i <= n; i+=2) {
j=1;
while(j < n) {
j = j + 2; 
x = x + 2;
} // end while } // end for
```

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Answer (score 0):

Speaking easily, you need to count how many operations your code does depending on *n* and keep only the function of *n* with highest **order** of magnitude, throwing the constants away. So in your case, polynomial with highest degree.

E.g. this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    System.out.println(i*2);
}
```

has *n* iterations and *a* operations per iteration, plus initialisation `i = 0`,  so **n*a+b** operation in total, where *b = 1* (warning: not really, see below).

Now, if you are interesting in **runtime**, you can multiple this by time of individual operations, but the exact number is not known and can be influenced by many things, like cash memory, so we just say it is another constant.

However, *a* and *b* are actually hard to determine. Let's say `++i` is one operation, `i*2` is another, and `println` the third, so 3 operations per iteration. But is it correct? How many operations `println` does? What if some of the operations which we write with one symbol lead to several actual operations?

Fortunately, these constants don't matter for big O notation:

- All functions of a form *a*f(n)* belong to the same class.
- Functions *s(n) = a*f(n) + b*g(n)* belong to the highest class out of f(n) and g(n)

Now what determines if *f(n)* is of higher order than g(n)? Speaking easily, it means that *f(n)* is always **larger** than *g(n)* **starting from some *n***, even if you run *f(n)* on a fast computer and g(n) on a slow one.

Let's say first algorithm has *n^2* operations and second *10*n* operations. Starting from *n > 10* first algorithm is slower (taking that each operations takes the same time, e.g. =1). So, you take a computer 100 times faster to run your n^2-algorithm. Now it runs much faster: in n^2/100 time! However, starting from n > 1000 it becomes slower than *n*-algorithm. Regardless of how fast your computer is, the n^2 algorithm will always be slower for large enough *n*. This is a property of the algorithm itself, regardless of the actual machine it runs on, and this is why it is important.